# POST parameters when submitting runtime generated content

Tags: html, http-post

I want to transmit data via POST to a remote script. A set of data is generated with Javascript and I would to know what's the best practice for gathering data before sending it. I tried to use:

```
<ul>
<li>Item added at runtime</li>
</ul>
```

I included all of these in a form, but I can't access the information on the server. What's the most popular approach for this problem? (I want to access the generated items on the server)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create hidden form elements.  `<ul>` and `<il>` are not form elements.

You can find an example here:  http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-set-form-field.htm

Now, another thing you can do is utilize AJAX to POST data.  There are a handful of frameworks that make this process very simple.  I recommend [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that usually, at least on the not compiled languages that work over web (php or classing asp f.e) this work is done with html hidden fields. When a post is executed, the user can't see that controls on the form but they actually travel to the server.

You can get this values without problem.

Have I understand your question correctly?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp